# There is need to use beforeEach + browser.get while testing with Protractor + AngularJS within MEAN.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, meanjs

I just began to use protractor in angularJS. I was facing an error:
`I App Already Bootstrapped with this Element 'document'` while changing ui-route states among my tests, and tried some workaround like `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true`, but it messed up. Although I recently noticed in [angular-seed](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed/blob/master/e2e-tests/scenarios.js#L16) the tests using: `beforeEach(function() { browser.get(''); });`

This way didn't crash my tests, but I know that as the tests grow up it will affect the performance/execution time. Looking in AngularJS docs I didn't find details about it.

Thanks!